# Registering custom path converters in django

Tags: python, django, oop, deployment, django-urls

I am learning Django custom path converter and its registration while I understand all the string integer sledge and uuid Types of url modifications but while registering a custom path converter I have problems and I didn't understand the syntax of its registration need help to solve this problem

```
class FourDigitYearConverter:
    regex = "[0-9]{4}"

    def to_python(self, value):
        return int(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return "%04d" % value
```

what is the use of regex class level variable , and the use of to_python , to_url methods below is Registration code but i cna understand it if i understand the above code

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter

from . import converters, views

register_converter(converters.FourDigitYearConverter, "yyyy")

urlpatterns = [
    path("articles/2003/", views.special_case_2003),
    path("articles/<yyyy:year>/", views.year_archive),
    ...,
]
```

I want to understand the core functionality of To_url and to_python method and the use of class level regex variable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is already defined here in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters)

The given converter tells you the year format the given url is going to accept.

class variable regex defines what numbers are valid and the length of digits.

`to_python` is used to convert given string to integer to be used inside the view.

`to_url` is used to convert to url that can be used in url dispatcher. The 04d means the missing digits will be filled with zeros. For example 98 will turn 0098 and % is just a placeholder that will be replaced with your given year.

In short the converter will accept any 1-4 digit number (for less than 4 digit it will prepend leading zero(s)).

Comment: thanks for explanation but the class level Regex variable is only declared but I didn't see its implementation

Comment: What implementation you want ? You have already done it in your question.